# list of pdf pages

Tags: table-of-contents, pdf

I need to add quite a few extra pdf files at the end of my report.
Is there a way to create a list of these pages (named list of evidence) following the table of contents?

Edit to question: I have realised how obscure it may all look now if you look at comments below. Let me clarify what it is that I'm after. I'm writing a report that needs numbered paragraphs. I also need to mark what paragraphs contain mention of evidence to statements in the report. This needs to be marked on the RHS in the margin (I'm doing that with the \ev command) The evidence needs to be added in a sequence of mention in the report at the end of the report. All of my evidence are pdf files (usually 1-5 pages long). So what I originally was after is a way to include a list of that evidence in the TOC (as sections), so that I can have a name of each evidence in section name to appear in the TOC and in the footer to identify it for the reader. I also don't want the evidence section heading to appear in the text (hence \invisiblesection). Hope this makes it a bit clearer now. Apologise for any confusion caused.

The intended ToC should look something like that

Contents

1. Section...................................2

   1.1 Subsection..............................2

   1.2 Subsection..............................3

   1.2.1 Subsubsection...............4

   ....

   ....

   List of Evidence

   Evidence 1....................40

   Evidence 2.....................41

   Evidence 3.....................46

   ....

Code EDIT#2

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,headheight=.4in,headsep=12pt,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


 %to get para numbers in the margins

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref}

 \newcounter{numpar}
 \newcommand{\np}[1][]{%
    \par
  \refstepcounter{numpar}%
  \noindent
    \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\textbf{\thenumpar}}%
    \qquad
   }%
  #1%
   \ignorespaces
 }

 %evidence counter
\newcounter{evidence}
\newcommand{\ev}{%
   \stepcounter{evidence}%
   \marginpar{\textbf{EV\theevidence}}%
 }

 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \lhead{\begin{footnotesize}
 Headerline 1\\Headerline2
 \end{footnotesize}}

 \rhead{\begin{footnotesize}
 headerline1
 \end{footnotesize}}

 \lfoot{\begin{scriptsize}
 \leftmark
  \end{scriptsize}}

  \cfoot{}

  \rfoot{Page \thepage}

  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

  \makeatletter
  \newcommand\invisiblesection[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
  \sectionmark{#1}}
  \makeatother

  \def\evidence#1{%#2{ %#3{%
  \label{#1}}


  \begin{document}

  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \tableofcontents
  \pagebreak
  \pagenumbering{arabic}

  \section{A sectoion}
  \np text
  \np text \ev
  \np text \ev
  \subsection{A subsection}
....
....
Main text of the report
....
....
End of text 
\pagebreak


\evidence{evi:abstract}\invisiblesection{EV1}\includepdf[scale=0.92,pages=1,pagecommand=    {\pagestyle{fancy}}]{evidence1.pdf}  

\evidence{evi:abstract}\invisiblesection{EV2}\includepdf[scale=0.92,pages=1,pagecommand={\pagestyle{fancy}}]{evidence2.pdf}  


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

*This solution was posted before the detailed clarification from the OP and may not reflect the actual output intended*

**Solution Idea**

Simply include the exhibits each as a separate chapter. This takes care of the primary issue of adding to TOC as well as other formatting issues. A small macro can
be written to simplify the usage.

**Solution**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\makeatletter
\def\startevidence{
  \clearpage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Exhibits}%
  \part*{Exhibits}
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{Evidence}
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}}
\makeatother

% \evidence{chapter heading}{label}{file}
\def\evidence#1#2#3{%
  \chapter{#1}
  \label{#2}
  \includepdf[pages=-]{#3}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}

\lipsum[1-100]

\chapter{Second Chapter}

\lipsum[51-100]

\startevidence

\evidence{Exposition}{evi:exposition}{evidence1.pdf}

\evidence{Specimen}{evi:specimen}{evidence2.pdf}

\evidence{Clarification}{evi:clarification}{evidence3.pdf}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Usage**

1. `\startevidence` starts the evidence part. This is just like the `\appendix` command, but it puts an extra page indicating the start of evidence. This is 
   added to the TOC as well.
2. Use macro `\evidence` to actually include each pdf file. This macro needs three arguments, name of the evidence which is more like a chapter heading, label for that chapter for later references, name of the pdf file.

**Modifications**

If you want the pdf files not to be added as chapters rather want to add them
as sections, simply modify the  `\evidence` macro.

Comment: hi MMA that's a good idea

I have altered the code to better fit my document, but I've got a slight problem. In the toc evidence number starts from 0, and I'm struggling to find how to fix it. Ideally I wouldn't want to have a numbered subsection in the toc for evidence.

Comment: @user43528 Does tweaking `\setcounter{chapter}{0}` or 
  `\setcounter{section}{0}` help? Simply comment out these two and see what happens. Then you can simply uncomment one at a time then again see what happens.

Comment: I was thinking of reducing depth of the toc from \startevidence to 1 (to number just sections) but that doesnt work either

Comment: @user43528 This is difficult to comment without seeing your code, but perhaps you will want not to use `\startevidence` at all and then change `\chapter` in the definition of `\evidence`  to `\section`. But again, it is very difficult to correct a code from remote.

Comment: i've put the most updated code into the question at the top of the page

Comment: @user43528 I will take a look at your code, does that mean you want the evidences added as sections with numbers?

Comment: Numbers are not necessary. I need them as sections (or subsections) so that the name of the evidence appears in the footer

Comment: the code I put above has the evidence with a counter in toc that starts from 0

Comment: @user43528 What you seem to be asking for and what you have coded looks different. Do you think you can prepare an image of your intended TOC and put it at some place?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12379/discussion-between-mma-and-user43528)

Comment: @user43528 You need to state very clearly what is wrong with the output you are getting with your updated code. Please clearly enumerate your problems at the end of your original post as **EDIT 2**. We are here to render help.

Comment: I have realised I've made a proper dog's dinner out of this! Apologise. I have updated the code in the question and explained in more detail what it is that I'm after.